# Easy to understand simple btc miner?

Tags: mining-software

For study purpose , is there any simple btc miner code that are very easy to understand as long as i understand the concept of btc mining ?

I've seen similar question on this website but the answer refers to either a messy code that very hard to understand or an outdated code that does not support the current btc miner protocol (e.g : DiabloMiner) , that's why i'm asking this.

Any code which last update is behind 2020 i consider as outdated.

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin.stackexchange.com. You will find it useful to take the [tour] and have a quick look at the [help]. Please note that "Easy to understand" is subjective and invites opinion-based answers which don't fit well here.

Comment: Mining is still exactly the same problem as it always has been in Bitcoin, so it's not clear to me why code examples that predate 2020 are outdated.

Comment: @Murch because of newer miner protocol

Comment: So, you would like to understand how Stratum V2 works?

Comment: The GBT and Stratum protocols that are used for mining in practice haven't changed since 2012-2013 somewhere. Before that time, the "getwork" protocol was used which is now obsolete. But any code you find from the last 4 to 8 years will probably work fine (4 years because segwit extensions may matter).